# Why should I prune old objects from Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, cleanup

What is the point of pruning old objects from Active Directory, especially computer accounts? If a computer is wiped or destroyed, then the stale computer account doesn't pose any security risk because it can't be used any more.

And I can't imagine that stale objects affect performance very much, because if they aren't being changed then they aren't being replicated.

So, what is the real motivation to keep Active Directory clean of stale objects?

Comment: Why do you flush a toilet? To get rid of unnecessary waste.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clarity, above all.

It's easier to find a needle in a pile of 5 pieces of hay, than it is in an entire haystack.

Answer (score 9):

It's all about the signal to noise ratio.  The more noise (old computer accounts, etc), the harder it is to pick out the important, useful, up-to-date information (signal).

If all of that stale, outdated, no-longer-correct information is left in there, eventually it's going to bite you in the ass.